# rtabmap odometry rate in rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/rtabmap/odom` runs at about 16Hz. However, when visualizing it in RViz, the vector seems to move at a much slower rate: 1-2 Hz, in spite of rviz reporting that it receives messages from rtabmap at the rate I expect. How can I make rviz visualize the rtabmap data at the same rate as the white line in the rtabmap viewer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250087/rtabmap-odometry-rate-in-rviz/) by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you compare with TF shown in RVIZ? For the Odometry display in RVIZ, there are "Position Tolerance" and "Angle Tolerance" parameters that can be set to 0 if you want to show all odometry messages.
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1